# When animating a control over a graphic, the graphic erases

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am using a transparent image, from this package
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

I am loading the image at the start and everything is fine.
To the left of the transparent image, I am loading a normal PictureBox.
The picturebox then starts moving towards another control that is to the right of the transparent image, meaning that the picturebox passes above the transparent image (which is intended).
When the picturebox moves past the transparent image, the part that the picturebox went over is "erased".
Can anyone help keep the transparent image not erased?

Animating the control function:

```
public static void SlideToDestination(Control destination, Control control, int delay, Action onFinish)
    {
        control.BringToFront();
        new Task(() =>
        {
            int curX = control.Left + (control.Width / 2);
            int curY = control.Bottom - (control.Height / 2);
            int desX = destination.Left + (destination.Width / 2);
            int desY = destination.Bottom - (destination.Height / 2);

            int directionX = desX > curX ? 1 : -1;
            int directionY = desY > curY ? 1 : -1;


            while (curX != desX || curY != desY)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (curX != desX)
                    {
                        control.Invoke((Action)delegate ()
                        {
                            control.Left += directionX;
                        });
                    }
                    if (curY != desY)
                    {
                        control.Invoke((Action)delegate ()
                        {
                            control.Top += directionY;
                        });
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(delay);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // form could be disposed
                    break;
                }
                curX = control.Left + (control.Width / 2);
                curY = control.Bottom - (control.Height / 2);
            }

            if (onFinish != null) onFinish();

        }).Start();
    }
```

Before Image:

[image]

After Image:

[image]

Comment: *I am loading the image*: what Image? Do you mean the snake-ish figure? What does *load* mean? Are you drawing that snake on a canvas that has a background Image (the *grid*)? The PictureBox is the one that contains the yellow face? -- Are you double buffering the canvas? What type of Control is used as canvas? It appears you're not invalidating the area where te PictureBox is moved. -- Why do you have a Task there? If you want to set  a delay, just change `public static void SlideToDestination()` to `public static async Task SlideToDestination()`, use `Task.Delay()` and await that method...

Comment: ... so you can remove all those `Invoke()` things. Note that you can pass a CancellationToken to the `SlideToDestination()` method, so you can call `[CancellationTokenSource].Cancel()` in case you need to stop the *animation*, for example when the Parent Form closes (or in any other case). -- BTW, the article you have linked contains a couple of major flaws (in the code described alone, I didn't check the whole thing), you should probably search for some more recent examples.

Comment: @Jimi What I mean by loading is that I create the transparent image during runtime and using this.controls.add(image)

Comment: The grid are transparent pictureboxes themselves. and yes, the picturebox is the one that contains the yellow face. I am not using any type of canvas. Regarding the article, I am just a beginner so I can't know what the flaws you are talking about are, and I tried to look but there aren't any recent articles on the subject. Thanks

Comment: Lastly, I switched to task.delay. It is necessary because without the task.delay the smiley erases the background grid as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. In the SlideToDestination function, after changing the location, all I needed to do was call Form1.snake.Update() where snake is the transparent image control. Then it redraws the snake every time after updating the location.